# Как копировать массив?

Tags: c++, массивы

Необходимо отсортировать ОДИН массив несколькими методами. Как после первой сортировки использовать первоначальный вариант массива для второй?

Answer (score 1):

Заранее скопировать.

```
int orig_massiv[N];

{   int massiv[N];
    memcpy(massiv,orig_massiv,N*sizeof(int));
    // Сортируем первым способом
    }
{   int massiv[N];
    memcpy(massiv,orig_massiv,N*sizeof(int));
    // Сортируем вторым способом
    }
```

Если все же С++ и `vector` - то еще проще:

```
vector<int> original;

{    vector<int> tosort (original);
     // Сортируем tosort первым способом
     }
{    vector<int> tosort (original);
     // Сортируем tosort вторым способом
     }
```

Comment: Заранее спасибо. в какой библиотеке находится memcpy?

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/c/string/byte/memcpy